# Specifying a certificate programmatically to WSClient

Tags: scala, ssl, playframework

In *one* part of a large Play 2.5 application, I need to make a TLS to a vendor's website.  The vendor has given me a certificate (a P7B cert, if that matters), and I am to use it.

If I were using `curl` it would be easy: `curl --cert thecert.p7b ...`

If I were only connecting to that website, I think it would be pretty simple: I could just set the `play.server.https.keyStore.path` variable in my application.conf.

But I need to use it in one case and not in others and the sole hint comes from this [tantalizing paragraph](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ConfiguringHttps):

> Another alternative to configure the SSL certificates is to provide a custom SSLEngine. This is also useful in cases where a customized SSLEngine is required, such as in the case of client authentication.

Well, heck.  How do I create a customized SSLEngine to support client authentication?

Answer (score 0):

The following compiles, and even runs if I don't use a cert, but I have to do more testing:

```
AhcWSClient(
  config = AhcWSClientConfig(
    wsClientConfig = WSClientConfig(
      ssl = SSLConfig(
        keyManagerConfig = KeyManagerConfig(
          keyStoreConfigs = Seq(KeyStoreConfig(
            filePath = Some(pathToCert),
            password = Some(password))))))))
.url(url)
.get
.map(_.body)
.map(println)
```